# Create a drop down list in excel using data from cube

Tags: excel, ssas, cube

I am currently working on populating the data from the cube on Excel. I am new to Excel. Can anybody suggest me how do we create a drop down list in Excel using the data from the cube as sourse.

I have a product list based on the category like:

```
Category         Products
---------       ----------
Finance          Audit
                 Contracting
                 Loans
Marketing        Target Market
                 Market segmentation
                 Market subsidies
```

All the data in the above table is got from the cube. Can we use cube functions as the source in the data validation - Lists.

Can anybody let me know on the possible ways of doing the above.

Comment: Can anybody suggest me on the way to do this. Or is it possible to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Select both the Category Field and the Product Field in Excel, then from the toolbar select DATA and then Filter. The filter can be used as a dropdown.

If you are looking for something else, please extend the question as it is very vague.